# How to update Craft 3 version of plugin when Craft 4 version is already released?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that initially was created for version 3.x of Craft, but was updated to be compatible with Craft 4. How can I update the plugin with some new features for Craft 3?

Comment: Did you look at https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/updating-plugins.html#high-level-notes yet?

Comment: Is this your own plugin? Or do you mean, that the plugin was made compatible for Craft 4 and new features are now added to the v4 compatible version but not being backported or provided in a separate v3 branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to have separate branches for the Craft 3 and Craft 4 version of the plugin. Then also increment the major version number of the Craft 4 version, and tag each release separately.

Comment: Will craft "understand" which branch is for Craft 3 and 4 when installing plugin?

Comment: Each branch will have a separate `composer.json` file with different version requirements, so yes. This is how I do it for all of my plugins. Look at the branches here, for example: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-retour